# Paper.js from pure javascript

Tags: javascript, canvas

I'm trying to make a game with paper.js but something is not working so i've simplified things and.. not working again.

I've tried to make with paper.js with already-made namespace `paperscript` but it was too hard to debug so i've tried to use [javascript directly](http://paperjs.org/tutorials/getting-started/using-javascript-directly/).

Even with super simple code moving a ball around the browser.. it is not working.

Here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <title>Bouncing ball</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="../../lib/paper.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var ball;

        function game(_view) {
            console.log("game!");
            ball = new Ball();
            this.view = _view;
            console.log(ball);
        }

        paper.install(window);
        window.onload = function() {
            var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
            paper.setup(canvas);
            view.onFrame = onFrame;
            game(view);
        }

        var Ball = Base.extend({
            initialize: function() {
                this.position = new Point(100, 100);
                this.velocity = new Point(3, 0);

                this.path = new Path.Circle(location, 25);
                this.path.strokeColor = 'black';
                this.path.fillColor = 'black';
            },

            iterate: function() {
                this.position += this.velocity;
                this.path.position = this.position;

                return this;
            }
        });

        function onFrame(event) {
            ball.iterate();
            //console.log(ball);
        };

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" resize></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

I'm keeping on getting this error:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot call method 'iterate' of undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you assign the `onFrame` handler, a setter function `setOnFrame` is called, which immediately invokes the frame handler.  Since `ball` is not initialized at this point, the function call fails.

```
setOnFrame: function(onFrame) {
    this._onFrame = onFrame;
    if (!onFrame) {
        delete this._onFrameCallback;
        return;
    }
    var that = this,
        requested = false,
        before,
        time = 0,
        count = 0;
    this._onFrameCallback = function(param, dontRequest) {
        requested = false;
        if (!that._onFrame)
            return;
        paper = that._scope;
        requested = true;
        if (!dontRequest) {
            DomEvent.requestAnimationFrame(that._onFrameCallback,
                    that._canvas);
        }
        var now = Date.now() / 1000,
            delta = before ? now - before : 0;
        that._onFrame(Base.merge({
            delta: delta, 
            time: time += delta, 
            count: count++
        }));
        before = now;
        that.draw(true);
    };
    if (!requested)
        this._onFrameCallback();  //here your onFrame function is called
},
```

If you look at [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dUnJF/1/), and make sure you set `break on exceptions` in your dev tools, you can see the stack.  The solution would then be to initialize `ball` before assigning the handler.

Comment: ??? yeah, ball is an instance of Ball.. the variable ball (lowercase) is the first line of the script..

Comment: Updated it with a little bit more investigation.

Comment: ok so. thanks for reviewing the answer. now what i does not understand is this: in your jfiddle (same as in my local example on chrome) if i comment `ball.iterate();` but uncomment `console.log(ball);` the consolle show me an object that inside `__proto__` has `iterate` as function. why? why it is not properly called?

Comment: and the, ok, if i try to initialize handler before the handler assignment.. there is no more exception BUT the ball is not moving at all..

Comment: You are adding the position to the velocity, instead of adding the [x and y components](http://jsfiddle.net/dUnJF/2/) individually.

Answer (score 2):

There is only one possible reason, `ball`is not yet defined when `onFrame` is called. Either assign `onFrame`after the creation of `ball`, or check `ball` inside `onFrame`.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a library [folio.js](https://github.com/frederickk/folio.js) for taking care of exactly this. It also handles animations. Here is your example using folio.js.

```
  <!doctype html>
<!--[if lt IE 7]>           <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8 lt-ie7"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 7]>              <html class="no-js lt-ie9 lt-ie8"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if IE 8]>              <html class="no-js lt-ie9"> <![endif]-->
<!--[if gt IE 8]><!--><html class="no-js"> <!--<![endif]-->
    <head>
        <!-- META -->
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
        <meta name="description" content="">



        <title>Ball</title>



        <script type="text/javascript" src="paper-core.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="paper.folio.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Properties
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // the core folio namespace
            var f = folio;

            // define ball variable
            var ball;



            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Setup
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            function Setup() {
                ball = new Ball();
            };




            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Update
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            /*
             *  Update() is called every frame
             */
            function Update(event) {
                ball.iterate();
            };



            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Draw
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            function Draw() {
            };



            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            // Classes
            // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
            var Ball = Base.extend({
                initialize: function() {
                    this.position = new Point(100, 100);
                    this.velocity = new Point(3, 0);

                    this.path = new Path.Circle(this.position, 25);
                    this.path.strokeColor = 'black';
                    this.path.fillColor = 'black';
                },

                iterate: function() {
                    this.path.position.x += this.velocity.x;
                    this.path.position.y += this.velocity.y;
                    return this;
                }
            });

        </script>



        <meta http-equiv="x-dns-prefetch-control" content="off"/>
    </head>
    <body>


        <canvas resize="true" id="canvas"></canvas>


    </body>
</html>
```